# Converting a character to an integer if the character is already a number in java

Tags: java, string, integer, character

I'm trying to read a string's character to get the numeric value.
String cardNumber = in.next();

```
  int currentIndex = cardNumber.length() - 1;
  while (currentIndex >= 0)
    {

      int smallValue;
      smallValue = Character.getNumericValue(currentIndex);
```

when smallValue runs, its not giving me the number. just a -1

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Character.digit(), but you are calling it with the array index instead of the element value *at* that index.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `currentIndex` to `Character.getNumericValue`. I think you actually want to pass one of the characters of `cardNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
int currentIndex = cardNumber.length() - 1;
while (currentIndex >= 0)
    {
         int smallValue = Character.digit(cardNumber[i], 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cardNumber` is a `String`, I believe this is what you want:

```
int smallValue = Character.digit(cardNumber.charAt(currentIndex), 10);
```